# Use Yup to display Firebase Auth error message

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, formik, yup

I am creating a login screen in React Native using Formik and Yup to handle the text inputs and error messages (email and password, tells me if email is invalid).

This works great if the user doesn't supply a valid email, but how would I get this to work for errors that Firebase checks (eg email already exists) and use Yup to display this error?